# How to delete column of data frame if row contains a certain value?

Tags: r

Suppose I have data frame `A`. If `A[I,j]=="z"`, I want to delete column `j`. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean for a specific row, or all rows? If the former, use:

```
A <- A[grepl('^z$', unlist(A[i,]))]
```

Where i is the row where the character 'z' is potentially located. If the latter, could just use a for loop to do across all i.